# linkedin api - Troubles with admin permission

Tags: api, http, request, linkedin-api

I am currently working on the linkedin API and i have this following trouble when i'm doing requests to [manage company page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages) :

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Member does not have permission to get company.",
  "requestId": "J7G7HP7VON",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1519820959291
}
```

I want to recover data for this request :
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/[Company_ID]/historical-follow-statistics?oauth2_access_token=[Access_Token]&time-granularity=day&start-timestamp=1517097600000&format=json

The cibled account have admin right on the linkedin page of the company so i don't understand why it's blocking.

Moreover, i tried this same request with the [API tester](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22%2Fcompanies%2F%7Bid%7D%2Fhistorical-follow-statistics%3Fformat%3Djson-get%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22time-granularity%22%3A%22day%22%2C%22start-timestamp%22%3A%221517141375625%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22json%22%2C%22parameters_name_1%22%3A%22format%22%2C%22parameters_value_1%22%3A%22json-get%22%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22970610%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D) and it works well.

Is somebody can help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You must required permission rw_company_admin to your linkedIn App please check your LinkedIn app permission settings after that you can able to manage your company details.

you can check out LinkedIn docs for Dev : [LinkedIn Company Manage API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages)

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem, and it seems that we are required to apply for the [LinkedIn Partner Developer Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program) in order to gain enough access to the API.